# How to fill and submit a Login Form on a Website with Java in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, html, http

I am currently working on a Java Android App which should connect to a website and get a JSON-Stream from there. However you have to login to the website first. I've made a form in the App where you pass your username and password. My goal is that both values will fill the form and submit it. Then you are logged in and can do the new HTTP-Request to get the JSON-Stream. The Website doesn't offer an API or Webservice. Doing it with WebView is not an option.

Libaries like HttpUnit don't work with Android Studio.
It seems like there is no real alternative for it.
With WebView it would be possible to use JS to fill it, however I want to avoid that.
JSoup doesn't seem to work to fill out html-forms.

I am looking for a solution to get the username and password field of the HTML-Form and be able to submit it by using the submit button.

Is there any good alternative to HttpUnit where I can fill and submit web forms with values from user inputs by getting the fields by their ID or name?

Comment: check this to learn how to define javascript interface developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

Comment: I want to avoid WebView. I would have to manipulate the whole site to make it effective that way.